# Appending __NSCFNumber to a String in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add numbers to the end of a string, but can't do it! I think the issue is because of the object type of `_post.postID` (which I checked and it said it was a __NSCFNumber). Am I using stringWithFormat wrong?

```
NSString *jsonURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/api/get_post$id=%@", _post.postID];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonURL);
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Turns out the compiler or something was messing up. I copied, deleted, and then pasted the code and it worked. Screwy Objective-C!

Will delete this question.

Comment: Side note - shouldn't the URL be: `http://www.website.com/api/get_post?id=9` ? Note the dollar sign should be a question mark.

Comment: Haha, thanks @rmaddy! Would've probably caused a mild headache down the line

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `[_post.postID intValue]` . Try this code.

```
NSString *jsonURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/api/get_post$id=%d", [_post.postID intValue]];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonURL)
```

Comment: No you don't. Using `%@` with the `NSNumber` directly works just fine.